Radial functions in $H^1_0(B)$ and a Strauss type inequality
Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Denote by $\|\cdot\|$ the usual norm in $H^1_0(B)$. In (2) of the paper is said that
$$
|u(x)| \leq \frac{\|u\|}{|x|^{(N-2)/2}},
$$
for any radial function $u \in H^1_0(B)$. However, this inequality is proved in p. 802 of this another paper, just for functions in $C^\infty_{0,\textrm{rad}}(B)$. I can understand that the result is true for $u \in \overline{C^\infty_{0, \textrm{rad}}(B)}^{H^1_0(B)}$, by density. But how to show the result is also true for $u \in \{u \in H^1_0(B) : u \text{ is radial}\}$? Given $u \in \{u \in H^1_0(B) : u \text{ is radial}\}$, is it true we can find a sequence $u_n \in C^\infty_{0,\textrm{rad}}(B)$ converging to $u$ in $H^1_0(B)$?

To understand why it is standard typographical usage to write $|u|$ instead of $||u||,$ notice the difference in appearance between $|u||v|,$ coded as \|u\|\|v\|, and $||u|| ||v||,$ coded as ||u|| ||v||.

@MichaelHardy it is not necessary to make a comment that is so vertically stretched to make your point: the two different versions are already present in the paragraph-style prose.
